# Indexing multiple files at once into one solr document

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I am indexing some course data(id, name, summary) along with attachments associates with these courses. I am using Extract RequestHandler to index docs by passing literal fields.

now there are three conditions while indexing.

1. A course may have multiple attachments.
2. No attachments
3. A course may have exact one attachment.

looking over the issue. Solr-php-client Extract method doesn't seems to be useful. So my question is

1. how to index these binary files along with course data(one solr document) ?
2. how to map multiple docs/pdf with unique course id ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr API did not allow attaching multiple files with a single Solr document.
For our project, we had zip the multiple files into a single attachment which was attached with the Solr document.
You can also index these multiple documents as individual Solr Documents having the same Course Id and use the [Field Collapsing (Grouping)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) feature to display a Single course with the matches across attachments.

Comment: After using group.field clause with query  $response = $results->response; return null and throws notice Notice: Trying to get property of non-object. what may be wrong ?

Comment: not sure of that. Check for the exploded results as the response is different for grouped results.